# Cannot discard changes because of file name

Tags: git

I have a frustrating issue with my git repos which I cannot resolve after many tries. I have two images named `amex.png` and `visa.png`. I remember renaming these to `Amex.png` and `Visa.png` and committed these changes. For some unknown issues, git now always show these files as `modified` no matter what I do to them.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/assets/images/amex.png
    modified:   app/assets/images/visa.png
```

I use `git checkout -- app/assets/images/amex.png` to discard changes but it instead shows me new file as `modified`

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/assets/images/Amex.png
    modified:   app/assets/images/visa.png
```

Again, if I run `git checkout -- app/assets/images/Amex.png`, it would again show the first file name `amex.png` in git status. It seems to be falling into a loop. I need to break this loop somehow.

It does not affect to my development code but it is annoying because I always have to pay attention to them when committing my code. I believe that I can just remove all current code and clone my repos again but I want to hear from you so that I can resolve it in the future.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am on Mac OSX (macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.
*Note: the following will lose all uncommitted changes in your repo*

Start by ensuring you have no untracked files in that directory. With git, you can just type delete the whole directory, then reset hard. I'd try something like this:

```
rm -rf app/assets/images/
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will remove the whole directory, then reset to the latest git commit you have (readding these files)

Another option is to clean your branch with

```
git clean -df
```

As per [Git documentation on git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean/2.2.0)

> git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree

**Description**

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that
>   are not under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option
>   is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example,
>   be useful to remove all build products.
>
> If any optional ... arguments are given, only those paths are
>   affected.

**Options**

> -d Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is
>   not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to
>   remove such a directory.
>
> -f
>   --force If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to run unless given -f, -n or -i.

Comment: This does not work, it still show these images as `modified` after `git reset`, same thing for `git clean`